# Specific subset of $\mathbb{Z}_p^d$ and its "suspicious" cardinality

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

> Let's consider finite field $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ with $p\equiv 1 \pmod 4$.
> Then there is an element $i\in \mathbb{Z}_p$, such that $i^{2}=-1$.
>
> Suppose that $\mathbb{Z}_{p}^d$ is a $d$-dimensional vector space over
> $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Suppose that $d=2m+1$, where $m$ is a multiple of $4$.
> Define the set of vectors $v_1,\dots,v_m \in \mathbb{Z}_p^d$ by
> $$v_1=(1,i,0,\dots,0), \ v_2=(0,0,1,i,0,\dots,0),$$  $$\
>  v_3=(0,0,0,0,1,i,0,\dots,0), \dots,\  v_m=(0,\dots,0,1,i,0).$$
>
> We'll need a natural number $n=\frac{1}{2}cp$. Now, define $A$ to be
> the first non-zero elements of $\mathbb{Z}_p$, that is,
> $A=\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$. So $A$ is an arithmetic progression of length
> $n$. Finally, let $u$ be the element $(0,\dots,0,1)\in
>  \mathbb{Z}_p^d$. Now we are ready to describe the set $E$.
> $$E=\{t_jv_j+au: j=1,\dots,m, \quad t_j\in \mathbb{Z}_p, \quad a\in
>  A\}.$$
>
> Let's break this down. Any element in the set $E$ will have exactly
> two of the first $m$ pairs of entries as an element of $\mathbb{Z}_p$
> multiplied by $1$ and $I$, respectively, and the final entry will be
> from our arithmetic progression $A$. It follows that the size of $E$
> will $$|E|=p^mn=\frac{1}{2}cp^{\frac{d+1}{2}}.$$

This is actually an excerpt from the the unpublished book. When I read it very carefully I noticed some unclear and probably incorrect moments here. I'll try to point out these suspicious moments below.

1. The author picks a natural number $n=\dfrac{cp}{2}$. In order $A$ to be an arithmetic progression we see that $c$ should be even number and $n<p$ i.e. $c<2$ which lead to the case that $c=0$.
2. And I guess it is better to denote $E$ in the following way $$E=\{tv_j+au: j=1,\dots,m, \quad t\in \mathbb{Z}_p, \quad a\in
    A\},$$ because I guess $t_j$ looks a bit confusing.
3. Also I highly doubt that $|E|=p^m|A|$. I don't think that this is a correct answer.

Can someone explain am I wrong or not about those 3 remarks?

---

**EDIT:** I will try to provide actually what the author wants to prove. But first of all I need to write some elementary preliminary (this is really easy).

Suppose that $\mathbb{Z}_p^d$ is a $d$-dimensional vector space over finite field $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Define the distance on $\mathbb{Z}_p^d$ in the following way: for any $x\in \mathbb{Z}_p^d$ let $\lVert x\rVert:=x_1^2+x_2^2+\dots+x_d^2,$ where $x=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_d)$.

Let $E\subset \mathbb{Z}_p^d$ and define the distance set of $E$, that is,
$$\Delta(E):=\{\lVert x-y\rVert: x,y\in E\}.$$

**Proposition (what the author wants to prove).** Suppose that $d$ is an odd number $d\geq 9$. For any small constant $c>0$ we can construct set $E\subset \mathbb{Z}_p^d$ with $|E|=\frac{1}{2}cp^{\frac{d+1}{2}}$ for which $|\Delta(E)|<cq.$

*Proof:*

Let's consider finite field $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ with $p\equiv 1 \pmod 4$.
Then there is an element $i\in \mathbb{Z}_p$, such that $i^{2}=-1$.

Suppose that $d=2m+1$, where $m$ is a multiple of $4$.
Define the set of vectors $v_1,\dots,v_m \in \mathbb{Z}_p^d$ by
$$v_1=(1,i,0,\dots,0), \ v_2=(0,0,1,i,0,\dots,0),$$  $$\
 v_3=(0,0,0,0,1,i,0,\dots,0), \dots,\  v_m=(0,\dots,0,1,i,0).$$

We'll need a natural number $n=\frac{1}{2}cp$. Now, define $A$ to be
the first non-zero elements of $\mathbb{Z}_p$, that is,
$A=\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$. So $A$ is an arithmetic progression of length
$n$. Finally, let $u$ be the element $(0,\dots,0,1)\in
 \mathbb{Z}_p^d$. Now we are ready to describe the set $E$.
$$E=\left\{\sum_{j=1}^{m}t_jv_j+au: t_1,t_2,\dots,t_m\in \mathbb{Z}_p, \quad a\in
 A\right\}.$$

Let's break this down. Any element in the set $E$ will have exactly two of the first $m$ pairs of entries as an element of $\mathbb{Z}_p$
multiplied by $1$ and $I$, respectively, and the final entry will be
from our arithmetic progression $A$. It follows that the size of $E$
will $$|E|=p^mn=\frac{1}{2}cp^{\frac{d+1}{2}}.$$

Now, for any two elements in $E$, say $x=\sum \limits_{j=1}^{m}t_jv_j+au$ and $y=\sum \limits_{j=1}^{m}s_jv_j+a'u$ we can compute the distance between to be

$$\lVert x-y\rVert=\lVert t_1v_1-s_1v_1\rVert+\dots+\lVert t_mv_m-s_mv_m\rVert+\lVert u(a-a')\rVert=$$
$$=0+\dots+0+\lVert u(a-a')\rVert=\lVert u(a-a')\rVert=(a-a')^2$$

This computation is valid because of the following $$\lVert z_1+z_2+\dots+z_n\rVert=\lVert z_1\rVert+\dots+\lVert z_n\rVert+2\sum \limits_{1\leq i<j\leq n} <z_i,z_j>$$ and the vectors $t_1v_1-s_1v_1,\dots, t_mv_m-s_mv_m$ and $au-a'u$ are mutually orthogonal.

So, every distance determined by pairs of points in $E$ will be of the form $(a-a')^2$. Since $A$ is an arithmetic progression, the set of these distances can be no larger than $2n-1$. By definition of $n$, $2n-1=cp-1$. Therefore, we have a set with size $\frac{1}{2}cp^{\frac{d+1}{2}}$ that determines fewer than $cp$ distinct distances.

Comment: too m,any letters. What happens when $m=4$  and $d=9?$

Comment: @WillJagy, probably too many letters but this is really elementary.

Comment: @WillJagy, If $m=4$ and $d=9$ then my answer for $|E|$ is just $4p|A|-3$

Answer (score 1):

I can’t be sure without knowing what the author goes on to do with $c$, but I suspect that the answer to your first question is that $c$ is not necessarily an integer, but rather is simply $\frac{2n}p$, where $n$ is some positive integer less than $p$.

It is definitely not better to denote $E$ by

$$\{tv_j+au:j=1,\ldots,m,\quad t\in\Bbb Z_p,\quad a\in A\}\,,\tag{1}$$

since this is not the set that the author has defined. $(1)$ implies that the same $t$ is used for each $j\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$, which is not the case: the author allows a different coefficient $t_j$ for each $j\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$. Thus, there are $p$ different possibilities for each of the $m$ coefficients $t_j$, and therefore there are $p^m$ different possibilities for the $m$-tuple $\langle t_1,\ldots,t_m\rangle$ of coefficients of the vectors $v_j$ of an element of $E$. There are $|A|$ possibilities for the coefficient $a$ of $u$, so there are altogether $p^m|A|$ possible choices of the coefficients that determine an element of $E$.

**Correction:** What the author has written is inconsistent. The calculation of $|E|$ and the use of $t_jv_j$ instead of $tv_j$ in the definition of $E$ suggest that the author actually intended $E$ to be

$$\left\{\sum_{j=1}^m(t_jv_j+au):t_j\in\Bbb Z_p\text{ for }j=1,\ldots,m\text{ and }a\in A\right\}\,,$$

and I unconsciously inserted the summation when I read it. However, both what is actually written and the verbal description that follows the definition $E$ indicate that the author intended $E$ to consist of the objects $tv_j+au$ for $t\in\Bbb Z_p$, $j\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$, and $a\in A$. In that case you’re quite right in thinking that it would be better to write simply $tv_j+au$, and of course the value for $|E|$ would indeed be wrong. It may be necessary to check with the author, if that is possible, in order to determine what is actually intended here.

Comment: Dear Prof. Scott! I am very thankful that you paid attention to my post. But to be honest I did not understand neither of your answers. 1) What do you mean by "elements of $A$ have not been reduced modulo $p$, so that $n$ need not be less than $p$. 2) In my notation for $E$ it does not mean that the same $t$ is used for each $j$. 3) Did not understand it at all. Could give more details or examples, please? I'd be so thankful for explanation

Comment: @ZFR: I meant that if $p=5$ and $n=6$, for instance, then the author may be allowing $A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, which, when reduced modulo $5$, becomes $\{1,2,3,4,0,1\}$. However, on further thought I see even without knowing what the author intends to do with $E$ that this causes some problems, so I will be changing that part of my answer: I suspect that $c$ is not necessarily an integer and is simply $\frac{2n}p$, where $n$ is an integer less than $p$. \\ Your notation **does** imply that there is a single $t$ for each element of $E$. ...

Comment: ... The computation of $|E|$ is basic combinatorics. There is one element of $E$ for each $(m+1)$-tuple $\langle t_1,\ldots,t_m,a\rangle\in\Bbb Z_p^m\times A$, so $$|E|=\left|\Bbb Z_p^m\times A\right|=p^m|A|\,.$$

Comment: I am still confused about part 2. For example, suppose we have vectors $v_1,v_2 \in \mathbb{Z}_p^d$ and consider the set $S=\{tv_j: t\in \mathbb{Z}_p, j=1,2\}$. Is it different from the set $S'=\{t_jv_j: t_j\in \mathbb{Z}_p, j=1,2\}$?

Comment: I guess that I have a wrong understanding of the structure of the set $E$. That is why I have issues. Can you explain how the elements of $E$ look like?

Comment: @ZFR: Each element of $E$ has the form $$t_1v_1+t_2v_2+\ldots+t_mv_m+au$$ for some coefficients $t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_m\in\Bbb Z_p$ and $a\in A$; does that help?

Comment: Wow that makes sense why the cardinality of $E$ is equal to $p^m|A|$. But the author writes it as $t_jv_j+au$ instead of the $\sum \limits_{j=1}^{m}t_jv_j+au$?

Comment: @ZFR: You’re right: I unconsciously inserted a summation. And what the author says immediately below the definition of $E$ suggests that he really did mean the set of objects of the form $t_jv_j+au$. In that case your version of $E$ would be fine, and $|E$ would be $pm|A|$. If you are able to get in touch with the author, I would ask what is intended here. The cardinality and the use of $t_jv_j$ instead of $tv_j$ suggest that he wants sums, but the absence of $\sum_j$ and the verbal description of elements of $E$ contradict that.

Comment: I guess you meant $pm|A|-m+1$, right? Because we are overcounting the zero vector $m$ times.

Comment: @ZFR: I think that we’re both wrong: there are $(p-1)m|A|$ with $t\ne 0$ and $|A|$ with $t=0$, for a total of $(pm-m+1)|A|$.

Comment: Dear Prof. Scott! Please sorry that I am bothering you. But I added an edit too my post where I provided the complete reasoning in order to understand what is going on. So my question is this: 1) I am still confused about this natural number $n$ and small $c$. 2) In the last paragraph the author says that the set of differences is not larger than $2n-1$. But I guess it should be $n$ since we are raising them to the square. I'll highly appreciate your help!

Comment: Dear Prof. Scott! Could you help me with my questions which I've asked in the above comment, please?

Comment: @ZFR: I will look at it, but it will have to wait until I get online tomorrow, which won’t be for about 12 hours.

Comment: Sure! Thanks you so much!

Comment: Dear, Prof. Scott! I was wondering about your clarification on this post.

Comment: Sorry to bother you. I just want to ask if you will post the answers to my questions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @ZFR: I really have to apologize: I had a minor emergency at home and have had almost no time for MSE. What you’ve done in your edit mostly looks good, but I would expect $\|x\|$ to be $\left(x_1^2+\ldots x_d^2\right)^{\color{red}{1/2}}$. You don’t need inner products to justify the computation: $\|x-y\|$ has the form $\sum_ir_iv_i+(a-a')u$ for $r_i\in\Bbb Z_p^d$, which is of the form $$\langle r_1,r_1i,\ldots,r_m,r_mi,a-a'\rangle\,,$$ and the sum of the squares of the components is $$r_1^2-r_1^2+\ldots+r_m^2-r_m^2+(a-a')^2=(a-a')^2\,.$$ The possible values of $a-a'$ run from $1-n$ ...

Comment: ... up through $n-1$, so there are $2n-1<cp$ possible values.

Comment: By $\lVert x \rVert $ we mean actually $x_1^2+\dots+x_d^2$ but not square root since we are in finite field. Please sorry for late reply!